# Flask 404 page not found

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm writing a small application in Flask.

run.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True, port=9001)
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <select id = "foo">
        {% for item in Citydata %}
            <option value = {{ item.link }}> {{ item.name }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <a href="/new">Click here</a>

{% endblock %}
```

new.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p>gafgafgadfgaerwgtdfzgaergdfzgaergaergaergt</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and lastly views.py

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import traceback


class City_Link(object):
    name = ""
    link = ""

    # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer
    def __init__(self, name, link):
        self.name = name
        self.link = link


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    URL = 'http://www.amis.pk/DistrictCities.aspx'
    City_Data = scrape(URL)
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Home',
                           Citydata=City_Data)

@app.route('/new/<data>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new(data):
    return render_template("new.html",
                           title='Home',
                           link = data)


def scrape(url):
    data = []
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml")
        table = soup.body.find(id='TABLE1')
        for row in table.findAll("tr"):
            heads = row.findAll("a")
            for head in heads:
                data.append((City_Link(head.text.strip(), head.attrs['href'])))
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    return data
```

When i click on the "Click me" href in index.html It gives me a 404 not found on the template new.html. I dont understand why because I followed a basic tutorial. I tried changing ports and it worked. But then I tried to update the code and it broke the link again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason this happens is because flask registers /new and /new/ to be two different routes.

It also looks like you're not actually passing in any data to the data variable anyway. You can temporarily fix this issue by changing your link to point to

```
/new/something
```

But that doesn't totally address the problem. I recommend adjusting your template code to make use of flasks excellent url_for function. You can find the extended documentation for it here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for

When we adjust your code, it should look like:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('new') }}">Click here</a>
```

And that data variable looks like it's not even used! Let's just strip it out totally!

```
@app.route('/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
    return render_template("new.html",
                           title='Home')
```

This has altered your code, and I may not have enough information about your use case. If this modifies it beyond being usable for your application, let me know and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.